# Usage of "aïeul" vs "grand-parent"?

Tags: vocabulaire, usage, choix-de-mot

I've just encountered *aïeul* for the first time and am uncertain of its tone or difference of meaning vs the more common *grand-parent.* At least I think it's more common? Am I mistaken?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Historiquement et de manière conforme à son étymologie, *aïeul* désigne effectivement d'abord et seulement le grand-père. (Et son féminin *aïeule*, la grand-mère)

Il s'est très rapidement (début XIIIe) étendu au sens d’ancêtre en général. (C'est à dire sans indication précise de génération.)

Attention : Depuis le XVIIIe siècle, on marque la distinction entre le sens restrictif et le sens étendu au pluriel :

- *les aïeuls* (les grands-pères) *les aïeules* (les grands-mères)
- *les aïeux* ( les ancètres )

Aïeul au sens de grand-père est plus littéraire que grand-père.
Dans la langue courante, il n'offre guère d'intérêt que par la possibilité d'être préfixable (*bisaïeul, trisaïeul, quadrisaïeul*...) ce qui évite les lourdeurs d'un *arrière-grand-père, arrière-arrière-grand-père*...

EDIT : [Les ngrams donnent probablement raison à Laurent S.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a%C3%AFeul%2C%20grand-p%C3%A8re&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Ca%C3%AFeul%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Ba%C3%AFeul%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BA%C3%AFeul%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cgrand%20-%20p%C3%A8re%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bgrand%20-%20p%C3%A8re%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BGrand%20-%20p%C3%A8re%3B%2Cc0)  Cf ci-contre.

Comment: Très bonne réponse, mais en ce qui concerne "évidemment plus littéraire"--- c'est pas évident pour ceux dont la lange maternelle n'est pas le français!

Comment: @Aerovistae : I stand corrected and apologize. I edit at once.

Comment: Si de nos jours je devais parler de la bisaïeule de ma fille à qui que ce soit, je doute que beaucoup de gens comprennent que je parle de son arrière-grand-mère...

Comment: @Laurent S. <mode_trolling> Sauf que... si je te demande combien ta fille a de trisaïeuls... tu me répondras beaucoup plus vite que si je te  demande combien elle a d'arrière-arrière-grands-parents... ;) </mode_trolling>

Comment: @aCOSwt > Maintenant, oui, mais je dois avouer que jusqu'à la lecture de cette  réponse je faisais l'amalgamme en ailleuls et ailleux, et ne l'ayant de mémoire jamais employé je n'avais jamais réalisé que les bisaïeuls etaient les arrière-grands-parents... J'avais juste en tête une notion de "lointains ancêtres", qui ne sont au final pas si lointains que ca, on était encore 4 générations au resto hier :-)

Comment: It's interesting to throw grand-mere (gently) into the mix...https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a%C3%AFeul%2Cgrand-p%C3%A8re%2C+grand-m%C3%A8re&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Ca%C3%AFeul%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Ba%C3%AFeul%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BA%C3%AFeul%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cgrand%20-%20p%C3%A8re%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bgrand%20-%20p%C3%A8re%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BGrand%20-%20p%C3%A8re%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cgrand%20-%20m%C3%A8re%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bgrand%20-%20m%C3%A8re%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BGrand%20-%20m%C3%A8re%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BGrand%20-%20M%C3%A8re%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Il suffit de se souvenir qu'un trisaïeul est un arrière-bisaïeul.